# Periodic 10 second pauses/freezes every 15 seconds when copying files on all(!) LUKS encrypted ext4 hard drives (NVMe not affected)

Tags: encryption, luks, file-copy, freeze, nvme

I copied a 10TB file from a LVM on LUKS encrypted ext4 drive to another identically set up drive and noticed that the copy process goes for 15 seconds at full speed (~220MB/s), then pauses for 10 seconds (nothing is written to disk), then continues at full speed for 15 seconds, and so on..

From the time passed and the amount that has been written to disk I can calculate that the ACTUAL transfer speed (including the pauses) is ~130MB/s which corresponds to the 15s/10s pattern (15/25 = 60% and 60% of 220MB/s is 132MB/s).

It seems like there is some buffer running full!? What is going on?

It has to be related to the fact that the encrypted drives are hard drives because there is no such issue on my encrypted NVMe drive.

**Interesting things I have discovered so far:**

- There is NO such issue when benchmarking the drives using gnome-disk-utility
- There is NO such issue if the drives are unencrypted ext4 or ntfs => It has to have to do with the encryption and not the drives themselves
- The drives are not broken: I have tested this on four different equally encrypted drives, external and internal ones
- The issue exists on my old system (Linux Mint 19.3, Kernel 5.0, Intel 2500K) and on my new one (Linux Mint 21.2, Kernel 6.2, AMD 5600G)
- The issue also exists with other software doing the file transfer: e.g. creating lage volumes with Veracrypt
- It doesn't matter if I copy from one encrypted drive to the other or if i duplicate a file on one of the drives, the issue persists

**Additional information:**

- I have used the following drives for my tests: 2x WD Elements 20TB (external), 1x WD Elements 12TB (external), 1x WD Red 3TB (internal). Each is LVM on LUKS ext4 encrypted
- My system does not freeze/hang when the issue happens. When I google for this issue I mostly find users whose whole systems freeze when the copy pauses happen

Comment: how do you know that no data transfer happens during these pauses? To me, it sounds like the usual block device/filesystem buffers run full, because the hard drive is slower at writing that you are at reading, so, there's a certain amount of time that the kernel spends just writing without accepting new data to be written, then the amount of dirty (unwritten) pages fall below a threshold, and the buffer is again allowed to fill up at basically RAM speed, and so on. So, the hard drive is writing at its maximum speed all the time, the kernel is, for some size, accepting data into buffers faster.

Comment: If that were the case, why does it only happen if the drive is encrypted? Furthermore I can hear the drive "idling" during that 10 seconds pause and then starting to write again. Also iotop shows that nothing is written to disk during that time. Other than that the drive can go at way faster speed than just 130 MB/s like the benchmark shows where the issue does not not happen.